# D3 Radial Dendrogram Zoom Jitters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I've got a D3 radial dendrogram tree that I've applied d3.zoom to, but it jitters when I drag it. The zoom behaviour itself is fine, but the drag is not. I think there might be some issue with the way the 'g' element is translated (`width / 2, height / 2 + 20`).

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's a codesandbox of my tree: https://codesandbox.io/s/4zr43po6l9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change 'svg' to 'g', so the zoom affects the g element directly below the svg the zoom behaviour is attached to, and it's now smooth

```
let zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", () => {
      g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
 });
```

I'm not sure why it works like this to be honest

Perhaps changing the svg transform freaks out the event mouse x y position a bit as it bases its values on the svg, so you get that juddering effect?